# recursive multiple subscript and superscript with xparse

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, xparse, recursion

How can I define a new command with xparse, something like this:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\tensorkor{ m >{\SplitList{,}}o  >{\SplitList{,}}o }
{
 ?????
}
```

that i can execute

```
$  \tensorkor{T}{^a,_b,_c,^r,^f}  $
```

which should result in a code like this

```
$  {{{{{T^a}_b}_c}^r}^f} $
```

This is tricky? I dont get it with `ProcessList{#1}`

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tensorkor}{m >{\SplitList{,}}O{}}
 {\begingroup
  \mathsf{#1}%
  \newcommand\object{\vphantom{\mathsf{#1}}}%
  \ProcessList{#2}{\dotensorkor}%
  \endgroup}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dotensorkor}{m}
 {%
  {\object}#1%
 }
\begin{document}
$\tensorkor{T}[^a,_b,_c,^r,^f]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thas perfect :-), but how does it work;
Does this not produce? : `\mathit{T}\vphantom{\mathsf{T}}^a_b_c^r^f`, why does it make brackets arround?   ahhh i got it, vphantom is the phantom vertical space between each sub/superscript

Comment: @user4514 I'm not sure to understand: the result would be *different* with just `{}`.

Comment: @user4514 I still don't understand.

Comment: (corrected the comment, sorry!) 
The `\vphantom` does NOT change the super/subscripts position. You would get the same result, if you just used {}. Consequently, if you replace `T` with something higher, the superscript will be too low (unlike the use of vphantom in your solution would suggest). For the reason and a solution have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165499/vphantom-and-superscripts

Comment: @user4514 You're wrong and right at the same time. A pair of braces is missing; but an ordinary atom is supposed to be in the `\phantom`, not `\sum` or `\int`.

Comment: With the braces I added (thanks for noting), the superscripts are level with the overline.

Comment: Yes, it does work now. Sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Without using xparse. (Edited to provide) two versions, depending on whether the user actually wanted subscripts of subscripts (`\recursa`) or not (`\recursb`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\recursa[1]{%
  \def\theresult{}%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{index}{1}%
    \protected@edef\theresult{\bgroup\theresult\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname\egroup}%
  }%
\theresult%
}
\newcommand\recursb[1]{%
  \def\theresult{}%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \addtocounter{index}{1}%
    \protected@edef\theresult{\theresult\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname{}}%
  }%
\theresult%
}
\makeatother
\parindent 0em\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
What the user asked for:\\
$  {{{{{T^a}_b}_c}^r}^f} $

Producing what the user asked for:\\
$\recursa{T ^a _b _c ^r ^f}$

Perhaps this is what the user really wanted:\\
$\recursb{T ^a _b _c ^r ^f}$

\end{document}
```

[image]