# \vphantom and superscripts

Tags: superscripts

The superscripts position is exactly the same for these two statements:

`\vphantom{\int}^S` and `{}^S`

How can I get the superscript higher up?

**Edit**

The `\int`is just an example. Here is another one: `\vphantom{)}^S` and `)^S`.

Comment: in which mode? text based math or display based? It might also be an idea to explain a bit more about what you are trying to do. Perhaps there is a better solution than trying to hack something together manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The construct `\vphantom` is not a math operator, thus the rules for an ordinary math atom applies for the superscript. `\mathop` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int^S = \mathop{\vphantom{\int}}\nolimits^S
\]
\[
  \int\limits^S = \mathop{\vphantom{\int}}^S
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

With package `amsmath` an "empty" math operator can be declared with `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\vint}{\vphantom{\int}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \int^S = \vint\nolimits^S
\]
\[
  \int\limits^S = \vint^S
\]
\end{document}
```

In case of a larger closing delimiter, `\mathclose` can help, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \Biggr)^S = \mathclose{\vphantom{\Biggr)}}^S
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Superscript at invisible closing delimiter]

I do not know, the reason for the question. If only a lonely higher superscript is needed, then an invisible `\rule` or `\raisebox` will help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  {}^S < \rule{0pt}{2.5ex}^S < \raisebox{3ex}{$\scriptstyle S$}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Higher superscript]

Comment: Is this equivalent to a simple `{\vphantom{\int}}^S`? What about the `)^S`? It seems your solutions will produce a higher superscript than `)^S`.

Comment: @user4514: I have added some other cases in the updated answer.

Comment: @user4514 Yes, this is equivalent to `{\vphantom{\int}}^S`. See my answer where the reason of your problem is explained in detail.

Answer (score 9):

The reason is: the macro `\vphantom` expands to the `\mathchoice` primitive. This primitive puts the "choice item" to the math list. When the `^` follows, then nucleus of the atom is not created immediately before and you can read the TeXbook, page 291:

> `<superscript>`: If the current list does not end with an atom, a new Ord atom with all fields empty is appended.

Try this:

```
$ \int^S, {\int}^S  % <- both creates the same result, Ord or Op is irrelevant
  \mathchoice{\int}{\int}{\int}{\int}^S % <- this emulates \vphnatom{\int}^S
  % and the empty atom is inserted (see TeXbook) like: 
  \mathchoice{\int}{\int}{\int}{\int}{}^S
  % so the result is the same as:
  {}^S
$
```

You can solve your problem by:

```
$ {\vphantom{\int}}^S $
```

because the Ord atom is created with "choice item" as nucleus.

Note: Ordinary atom is not problem, problem is `\mathchoice`.

Comment: I've always wondered why `\vphantom` did not *always* behave exactly like its typeset counterpart.  Thanks.