# No caption number for figures and tables

Tags: floats, captions

I want to make some of my figures just without a number.

Instead of **Fig. 1: Caption.** I want simply **Caption.**

I tried to do `\caption*`, but it doesn't work for me even after using the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package upgrade.

Maybe there are another ways to do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You could use `\captionsetup` from the package `caption` that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{figure}
\caption{Une figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{figure1}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\caption{Une figure.}
% \addtocounter{figure}{-1} add this if you want the next figure to be numbered 2 
% otherwise it'll be numbered 3
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I got it. I used caption2 instead of caption. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: With this setup, the next (numbered) `figure` will be numbered `3` rather than `2`. To counteract this presumably unwanted effect, you could type `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before the start of the next `figure` environment.

Comment: Hello @Mico you can also add \addtocounter{figure}{-1} after \caption, it works.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi - Thanks. I believe your suggestion is implied by mine. What's crucial is that `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` is executed *before* LaTeX encounters the next numbered `figure` environment and its associated `\caption` directive. Whether `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` is executed immediately after `\caption` or sometime later (as long as it's *before* the next `\caption` statement) is less important.

Answer (score 44):

You can also use `\caption*` when using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) which keeps only the caption title.

You may do something else what did not work, but this example works as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics{figure1}
\caption*{Caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has the bonus to avoid incrementing the figure counting without the necessity to use `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest way is to enter the caption not enclosed in the `caption{}` command.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Fig_test.png}
  \caption{This with float name and number}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Fig_test.png}\par
  This with just the caption
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I advise against this approach. Notice that the spacing is inconsistent. The one with the proper `\caption` macro has about a line worth of vertical space below the picture and the one below has much less than that.

Comment: I guess a `\vspace' could fix the problem.

Comment: And now you need to guess the amount of `\vspace` as well :/

Comment: `\vphantom{Figure 1}` will match the vertical height of text "Figure 1" without needing to mess with `\vspace`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165499/vphantom-and-superscripts