# How to stop numbering for a figure

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

so I have multiple graphics in my Latex document, and have wrapped them in figure enviornments for easy positioning. How can I have one of my figures not count towards the overall figure counter in this chapter? 
So I have figure A, it contains three subcaptions. I give them each a \subcaption* (so the one without the label), and then I have figure B and want to give it a caption, and want it to be called Figure 1.1 (instead of Figure 1.2)

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}
This is Figure A
\begin{figure}[h] % Figure A (should be excluded from the count)
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);   
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(i)}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(ii)}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(iii)}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure} \par\noindent
This is Figure B:
\begin{figure}[h]\centering\begin{tikzpicture}  % Figure B (should be included into the count and here be % Fig. 1.1.
    \draw (0,0) circle (20pt);
\end{tikzpicture}\caption{B}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Comment: What about `figure*`?

Comment: @Sigur sadly doesn't change anything at all for me. maybe I'm not getting what you mean...

Comment: @Sigur `figure*` has nothing to do with numbering. That is a whole width float in a `twocolumn` document.

Comment: @JosephHolten you can probably add `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` to your first figure.

Comment: @cgnieder it worked perfectly! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subcaption` package needs to increase the `figure` (or `table`) counter in order to affix the right number to the subfigure number even when the main caption is at the bottom.

When it finds the `\caption` command (which will step up the counter), it steps the counter down so the final results agree. In your case the counter is never stepped down.

Solution: step down the counter manually. I suggest defining a `\nocaption` declaration to this effect.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nocaption}{\addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

This is Figure A

\begin{figure}[htp] % Figure A (should be excluded from the count)
\centering

    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);   
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(i)}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(ii)}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}\subcaption*{(iii)}
    \end{subfigure}

\nocaption

\end{figure}

This is Figure B:

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (20pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\caption{B}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add `\caption{A}` into the closing line of your first `figure`.
`\caption{A}\end{figure} \par\noindent`

But similar to Sigurs comment, you would get 2 separate `figures`, listed as 1 and 2 and no `subfigures`.
As far as i know, there is no deeper nesting to `subsubfigures`.

Comment: sorry, you didn't get what I was looking for. I want to seperate figures, but the first one should not increase the counter of figures. It should be invisible to the counter. So the figure counter **before** it would be at Fig 1.x and the figure counter **after** it should be Fig. 1.(x+1) NOT 1.(x+2) as it is normally.

Comment: Maybe this article helps [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/skip-figure-counter) you.