# Positioning list in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

Currently my list of figures looks like this
`List of Figures
     Figures 1 ........................x
     Figures 2.........................x`

How to make like this?
`List of Figures
 Figures 1 ........................x
 Figures 2.........................x`

Thank you

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openleft]{book}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{chapter 1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{images.png}
\caption[Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}]{caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{chapter 2}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{images2.png}
\caption[Figure~\ref{fig:fig2}]{caption2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You're description is not really useful because we don't see which code produces this output. Please post a compilable, minimal document that has this issue

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX. Please, add a minimal working example, i.e. a compilable code which would help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @bmv, but it's not working

Comment: @zeirash Actually, your code is not compilable. You should add `\usepackage{graphicx}` in order to use `\includegraphics`. I don't know what is not working for you, see my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you desire to have no indentation before the entries of the list of figures, you should use `tocloft` package, and set `\cftfigindent` to `0pt`. See code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openleft]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{chapter 1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption[Figure~\ref{fig1}]{caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{chapter 2}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\caption[Figure~\ref{fig2}]{caption2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah yes thank you, your code work. I just realized why my code won't work. It's because I use this package `\usepackage[listformat=empty]{caption}`. I use that because I want to remove the 1.1 and 2.1 before the name of figures. Is there any suggestions how to remove that?

Comment: See question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199207/no-caption-number-for-figures-and-tables

Answer (score 0):

The LOF is formatted by `\l@figure` which in turn calls `\@dottedtocline` to add the indentation etc.  The figure/caption number is added by `\numberline`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openleft]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}[2]% #1 = \numberline[number}{text}, #2 = page
{\bgroup
  \let\numberline=\@gobble
  \@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{0pt}{#1}{#2}%
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{chapter 1}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
%\includegraphics{images.png}
\caption[Figure~\thefigure]{caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{chapter 2}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
%\includegraphics{images2.png}
\caption[Figure~\thefigure]{caption2}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```