Appendix and Page text on List of Appendices
Currently, I have this MWC.
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{LIST OF APPENDICES}
\newlistof{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\renewcommand{\theappendices}{\Roman{appendices}}

\newcounter{appendixcounter}
\renewcommand{\theappendixcounter}{\Roman{appendixcounter}}

% Define a counter for appendix entries
\newcounter{appendixentrycounter}[appendixcounter]

\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{\protect\numberline{\theappendixcounter}#1}
}

\newcommand{\newappendix}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{appendixcounter}
  \setcounter{appendixentrycounter}{0}
  \vspace*{12mm}
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
    \textbf{Appendix \theappendixcounter} \\[1em]
    #1
  \end{center}
  \vfill
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{\protect\numberline{\theappendixcounter}#1}%
}

\newcommand{\appendixentry}[1]{%
  \subsubsection*{#1}%
  \phantomsection
}

Now, how do I adjust this so that there are text "APPENDIX" and "PAGE" above the Appendix numbers and Page numbers, respectively?
Please refer to the attached image.


Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as i can see they are ... Can you please show a short complete compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

For a single page you can use \addtocontents{apc}{APPENDIX\hfill PAGE}.

@JohnKormylo Your suggestion worked but the Appendix numbers are not aligned at the middle of the "APPENDIX" word. Is there a way to align it? I've tried your suggestion with the List of Tables and it was automatically aligned to the "TABLE" word.

The APC will be formatted by \l@appendices (presumably created by \newlistof).  Note that the number uses \numberline, which you may also need to edit.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410194/positioning-list-in-list-of-figures/410240?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C11.7012#410240 for example.
